# Listview that contain fixed listview

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to basically make a Settings Screen. Actually my screen look like that with Settings section that are composed of one title and a non-scrollable list view. I would like to put these sections in a list view to make the screen scrollable and to make every settings section following the last one.

Here is my actual screen.

[image: Actual screen]

And here is my code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: SettingSection('Communication', [
          SettingsPayload('Email', 'Switch', () => (print('Function :)'))),
          SettingsPayload('Notifications', 'Switch'),
        ])),
        Expanded(
            child: SettingSection('Hello', [
          SettingsPayload('Email', 'Normal', () => print('value'),
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          SettingsPayload('Notifications', 'Normal', () => print('hello')),
        ]))
  ],
));
```

How I build each list

```
buildlistSettings() {
return ListView.builder(
    physics: ScrollPhysics(parent: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      if (i < widget.listSettings.length) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildTileSettings(widget.listSettings[i]),
            Divider(),
          ],
        );
      }
    });
  }

@override


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
              height: 25.0,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 230, 233, 0.5), border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 230, 233, 0.5), width: 1.0))),
              child: Row(children: <Widget>[Text(
                widget.title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.blueGrey), 
              )])),
          Expanded(child: buildlistSettings()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `Container` with `ListView` in your code? You'll want a scrolling container of some sort (`ListView` if you have multiple items or maybe `SingleChildScrollView` if you're just using a single `Column` to contain all the children) at the root of your widget tree to get the scrolling behaviour.

Comment: I just tried this, but I think that is struggling because of my `Expanded` widgets :/

Comment: @DerekLakin I will add how i'm building each list

Comment: Is buildListSettings what's called for each SettingSection?

Comment: Yes it is called every time depending on the parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a set of problems here not least of which is trying to put a `ListView` inside a `ListView` (and having to turn off scrolling), but mostly the use of `Expanded` which tries to fill up all the space in the relevant direction, but inside another container, which is itself unbounded.

I would use a `ListView` at the root, then build up the children using simple `Column`, `ListTile` and `Divider` widgets. Here's a working example (duplicated your data to ensure there's enough to scroll):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          SettingSection('Communication', [
            SettingsPayload('Email', 'Switch', () => (print('Function :)'))),
            SettingsPayload('Notifications', 'Switch'),
          ]),
          SettingSection('Hello', [
            SettingsPayload('Email', 'Normal', () => print('value'),
                Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            SettingsPayload('Notifications', 'Normal', () => print('hello')),
          ]),
          SettingSection('Communication', [
            SettingsPayload('Email', 'Switch', () => (print('Function :)'))),
            SettingsPayload('Notifications', 'Switch'),
          ]),
          SettingSection('Hello', [
            SettingsPayload('Email', 'Normal', () => print('value'),
                Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            SettingsPayload('Notifications', 'Normal', () => print('hello')),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<SettingsPayload> payload;

  SettingSection(this.title, this.payload);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
              height: 25.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 230, 233, 0.5),
                  border: Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 230, 233, 0.5),
                          width: 1.0))),
              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  this.title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                )
              ])),
          _buildListSettings(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListSettings(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> items = List<Widget>();
    for (var setting in this.payload) {
      // TODO: Add logic here to determine what kind of setting widget to
      // create based on the payload.
      items.add(ListTile(
        title: Text(setting.title),
        trailing: Icon(setting.icon),
      ));
      items.add(Divider());
    }
    return Column(children: items);
  }
}

class SettingsPayload {
  final String title;
  final String type;
  final Function handler;
  final IconData icon;

  SettingsPayload(this.title, this.type, [this.handler, this.icon]);
}
```

You could use `ListView.builder` at the root level if your incoming settings data is variable and create `SettingSection` widgets for each item. Depends how you're handling your data.

Comment: that is exactly what i want ! Thank you so much